# I need to print out the amount of times each word was used in the passage from a specific url address

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of words that are associated with a specific url address and print the words in order with the amount of occurances they apear. Right now it reads the file in and counts the words, but it prints it out line by line, and not with a count for the whole passage. Any help to get it to read the whole thing and print out the words 
in the entire passage with their occurance would be great.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://webpagehere.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        int i=0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Line " + i + "\t" + line);
             // Create a TreeMap to hold words as key and count as value
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

String[] words = line.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]");
for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
  String key = words[j].toLowerCase();

  if (key.length() > 0) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
      map.put(key, 1);
    }
    else {
      int value = map.get(key);
      value++;
      map.put(key, value);
    }
  }
}

// Get all entries into a set
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

// Get key and value from each entry
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: entrySet)
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());


        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown host. Abort.");
    } catch (NoRouteToHostException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                      "Cannot reach remote host. Abort.");
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I take it you mean words in the actual web page, and not the url itself?

Comment: yes the words in the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the initialization an printing for the `Map` outside of your while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://webpagehere.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            int i=0;
            Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("Line " + i + "\t" + line);
                // Create a TreeMap to hold words as key and count as value

                String[] words = line.split("[ \n\t\r.,;:!?(){}]");
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    String key = words[j].toLowerCase();

                    if (key.length() > 0) {
                        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
                            map.put(key, 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            int value = map.get(key);
                            value++;
                            map.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.close();

            // Get all entries into a set
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

            // Get key and value from each entry
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: entrySet)
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown host. Abort.");
        } catch (NoRouteToHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot reach remote host. Abort.");
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working now. I knew it was something to do with my positioning, I just couldnt find the mistake.  Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: If you found this answer to be the most helpful, please click the check-mark on the left under the up- and down-arrows to "accept" the answer.

Comment: sorry, first time posting something

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` to store words and its occurrence is declared in the while loop. Just move the declaration out of while loop to make it work.

```
        int i = 0;
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, java.lang.Integer>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```